# How can I apply QuantileDiscretizer on a groupBy object in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I want to compute Quantiles on a dataframe after grouping it.

This is my sample dataframe:

```
 |id |shop|amount|
 |:--|:--:|---:|
 |1  |A.  |100|
 |2  |B.  |200|
 |3. |A.  |125|
 |1. |A   |25 |
 |2  |B   |220|
 |3. |A.  |110|
```

I want to bin the amount into low, medium and high, based on each shop.

So, I would group my dataframe like this.

`shop_groups= df.groupBy('shop')`

The mistake I did originally, was I applied the `QuantileDiscretizer` on the whole amount set as is, without grouping it by shop.

How can I do this on the shop_groups ?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: You might have meant to give more details to your question, by pointing out a possible solution which however you want input on scalability on. Changing a questions focus like that is perfectly fine. I got however the impression that your edit was more of a solution with some follow up thoughts. Feel free to to change your question (even by just reinserting what I deleted), I will not interfere again if you did not intend to show a solution. Also, in that case please accept my apology for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will take care of these points.

Comment: I forgot to mention (harmless in this case, do not worry). If you already have answers by other users, then you must be very careful with changing a question or even a questions focus. It might still be OK, but it usually is a problem, because it risks invalidating existing answer. There are no answers here yet, so no problem, but I wanted to mention that different situation, in which "moving target questions" are not appreciated.